# Compute the probability mass function

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint mass function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{C}{(x+y-1)(x+y)(x+y+1)}\;\;x,y=1,2,3,\ldots$$
Find the marginal mass function of $X$ and compute $C$

Comment: Have you made an attempt of your own?

Comment: I tried letting $X+Y=Z$ and computed the pmf for $Z$. I then tried to use it to get $C$ but got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) to find the marginal distribution you should get $C/(2 x (1+x))$ if I am not mistaken. To find the constant $C$ you want to use 
$$\sum _{x=1}^\infty \sum_{y=1}^\infty P[(X,Y)=(x,y)]=1$$ (you previous result helps in this matter) and the constant i believe is 2. Have fun :)